# Programmatically access Microsoft identity across Azure, VSTS, and Graph

Tags: node.js, azure, azure-devops, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

Is there a way with a single app to access Graph, VSTS, and Azure information? It seems access to each of these requires it's own app with origination and callback urls.

For Azure, I'm using NPM's passport-azure-ad in a node js app.

Ideally, I would like to combine VSTS build info, Azure service usage info, and User profile info.

Comment: Do you solve this issue?

Answer (score 2):

Each of the services you mentioned has their own API:

- [Azure REST API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/#components-of-a-rest-api-requestresponse)
- [Visual Studio Team Services REST API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/vsts/)
- [Microsoft Graph](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/)

This does not however mean that they also each need their own "app". When you register your application in Azure AD via the [Azure Portal](https://portal.azure.com) you're able to request access to a number APIs. Each `access_token` you receive will be tied to one API (called a "resource") but you can use the `refresh_token` to switch the targeted resource:

The only exception here is the VSTS REST API. While most APIs use the same identity provider, VSTS has their own. So for the purposes of VSTS, you will need to have the user authenticate separately. Obviously, that isn't a great user experience but there is a useful workaround: [Personal Access Tokens](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/integrate/get-started/authentication/pats?view=vsts).

Using a Personal Access Token for VSTS allows you to authenticate the user via Azure AD OAuth and get an access token you can use with Microsoft Graph and the Azure REST API. Once you've authenticated them, you can ask them to provide a Personal Access Token to access VSTS. This allows you to forgot asking the user to authenticate a second time since you'll store their PAT use it for any calls to VSTS.

Answer (score 0):

First, there is **Allow scripts to access OAuth token** option in the Phase of Build/Release definition, you can check this option and access the token through `System.AcessToken` variable.

To grant the permission for that user, you need to grant the permission(s) for **Project Collection Build Service (xxxx)** account.

Secondly, there are some tasks related to Azure (e.g. Azure PowerShell), that can access azure resources (The AAD application is associated to the Azure endpoint)

You can retrieve the necessary information in multiple task, then store the result in the variables through [Logging Commands](https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-tasks/blob/master/docs/authoring/commands.md) (##vso[task.setvariable]value), then combine them together.