# Acquire a unique token for both Graph and Azure DevOps APIs using Microsoft Identity

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-msal, azure-devops-rest-api

Is it possible to use the same access token to authenticate both Microsoft Graph API an Azure DevOps API?

When I authenticate for Graph and add scope for Azure DevOps, the token works for Azure DevOps but stops working for the Graph.

Thank you!

Comment: You could try to use Personal Access Token for VSTS to authenticate the user via Azure AD OAuth and get an access token you can use with Microsoft Graph and the Azure REST API. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50118266/programmatically-access-microsoft-identity-across-azure-vsts-and-graph

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it is not possible.

When you get the [jwt(JSON Web Token)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON_Web_Token) with  OAuth 2.0 flow,  every token just have one audience, it means one token is just for one resource, it can just call one kind of api. You could decode your token in https://jwt.io/, and see the `aud`, it should be the resource of devops, to call Microsoft Graph, it should be `https://graph.microsoft.com`.

Comment: In this case is it possible to issue one token for Microsoft Graph and an token for Azure DevOps and use them in parallel? Or when I acquire one token the last is invalidated? Thank you!

Comment: @MuriloMacielCurti If you use different ways to get the different tokens, of course you can.